# Java Swing JTextArea Horizontal Constraint only

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Is there a way in java swing to code:

"Constraint the width of JTextArea to W but allow JTextArea to expand vertically to contain all the linewrapped text'?

Comment: Personaly, I would delegate this kind of computation to LayoutManager.

Comment: That's what I would like to do, except for the horizontal constraint

Comment: This is all comes down to what are the surrounding containers, what are their layout managers and how do you want the global layout to adjust. A `GridBagLayout` can help you expand vertically. If you could post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org) we could help you more on this

Comment: As I begin to REMOVE some of the preferredSize settings I had BEFORE I converted to GridBagLayout, I am starting to see your point - I think it is already working the way I want it to

Comment: I ended up using MigLayout, but with what I have learned since, I could probably use GridBagLayout again.  I needed to differentiate between what constrained the cells and and what constrained the components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set the text area to W columns.
2. Set the wrap style & line wrap.
3. Add it to a scroll pane with a vertical scroll bar as needed, but no horizontal scroll bar.

Alternately if the content does not need to be selectable or editable, use a label with HTML & CSS to constrain the width.

Comment: I don't want a scrollbar - I want the box to display all the text.

Comment: Edittable no, but I WOULD like it to be selectable.